# Fields that are not real closed fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to find a field $F$ that is not a real closed field, but first the definition of a real closed field that I am using:

An ordered field $(\mathbf{R},\geq)$ is real closed if it satisfies the following two properties:

$(1)$Any positive element $x\geq0$ in $\mathbf{R}$ has a square root in $\mathbf{R}$; i.e. there exist $a\in \mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $x=a^{2}$.

$(2)$Any odd degree polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbf{R}$ has a root in $\mathbf{R}$.

I am thinking on a field that the part $(1)$ is satisfied but not part $(2)$. Aldo in one example in which the quotient of square classes is isomorphic to $\mu_{2}$.

Comment: In (1) if you start "any element $x \ge 0$" do not conclude $a \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.  Either start with $x > 0$ or else conclude without the "$\setminus\{0\}$".

Answer (score 3):

I presume $\mu_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$? If so, then the field of [(straightedge-and-compass) constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) real numbers is an example.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of [the quadratic closure of $\mathbb Q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_closed_field#Quadratic_closure) and $\mathbb R$ contains the square roots of all its positive elements, but does not contain any root of $X^3 -2$, so it is not real closed.